# NLTK 2.0 classifier batch classifier method

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

When I run this code it throws an error which I believe is due to the batch_classify method not being present in NLTK 3.0. I curious how to resolve this type of issue where something from an older version disappears in the newer version.

```
def accuracy(classifier, gold):
    results = classifier.batch_classify([fs for (fs,l) in gold])
    correct = [l==r for ((fs,l), r) in zip(gold, results)]
    if correct:
        return float(sum(correct))/len(correct)
    else:
        return 0

def apr (classifier, gold):
    results = classifier.batch_classify([fs for (fs,l) in gold])
    #gold_class_dict = defaultdict(list)
    #classifier_class_dict = {}
    sys_correct_dict = Counter()
    num_guessed = Counter()
    gold_num = Counter()
    num_right = 0
    total = 0
```

Comment: Why are you using an old version of `nltk`? Try `pip install -U nltk` on the terminal / powershell.

Comment: @alvas I think the question is about porting code from NLTK 2.0 to NLTK 3.0.

Comment: Hopefully this would help: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Porting-your-code-to-NLTK-3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method was renamed to `classify_many()` (I couldn't find documentation of NLTK 2.0 to check it, but I'm pretty sure that's what happened).

You have to replace all occurrences of `batch_classify(...)` with `classify_many(...)` in your code.
When moving from one major version of a library to another, you have to expect this kind of backwards-incompatible changes; they should ideally be documented in the changelog. However, I have to admit that in the past NLTK introduced backwards-incompatible changes even between minor versions, which I think is bad practice.